# Chat messages appearing in the wrong order

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I wrote a message in the IT security chat room that appeared at the top of live room, before the day's earlier messages: however the ordering of other messages leads me to believe that messages should appear chronologically.

[image: Message appearing before others]

Comment: I think this is an active bug with the realtime chat UI, actually. I've heard reports of it quite a few times, though never personally experienced it. Your post is at the normal position in [the actual transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/864750#864750), and I believe everyone else will have seen it in the correct position. I'd say I'd go fetch @balpha, but it appears he's right here anyway. ♪

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this <s>is</s> was a known issue that <s>appears</s> appeared in some cases when the message *before* went through some connection hickup.

Note though that if you look [at the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/864750#864750), the message is in the right place, and if you refresh your chat window, it'll be correctly ordered as well; this <s>is</s> was purely a display issue (which, nonetheless, <s>should be</s> is now fixed).